# to_datetime() in pandas returns a Categorical type rather than a datetime object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string-to-datetime

Here is a sample of the code:

```
data.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp, infer_datetime_format = True, utc = True)

data.timestamp.dtype

CategoricalDtype(categories=['2016-01-10 06:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-10 07:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-01-10 08:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-10 09:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-01-10 10:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-10 11:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-01-10 12:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-10 13:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-01-10 14:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-10 15:00:00+00:00',
                  ...
                  '2016-12-31 13:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-31 14:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-12-31 15:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-31 16:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-12-31 17:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-31 18:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-12-31 19:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-31 20:00:00+00:00',
                  '2016-12-31 21:00:00+00:00', '2016-12-31 23:00:00+00:00'],
                 ordered=False)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

```
data.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp, infer_datetime_format = True, utc = True).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

This worked.